# Extracting a specific link form an element based on a previous text-element

Tags: css, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I want to extract all available links and dates of the available documents (`"Referentenentwurf", "Kabinett", "Bundesrat" and "Inkrafttreten"`) for each legislative process (each of the gray boxes) from the [page](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/service/gesetze-und-verordnungen.html). My data set should have the following structure:

[Each legislative process is represented by one row and the information about the related documents are in the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0RIE.png)

Here is the HTML structure of the seventh legislative process:

[This is one example of the HTML-structure of the elements including the legislative processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPrG8.png).

Extracting the dates of each document per legislative process is not a problem (simply done by the investigation whether the "`text()"-element includes e.g. "Kabinett"`).

But extracting the right URL is much more difficult because the "text()"-elements (indicating the document type) are not directly linked with the ""-elements (including the URL).

I'm trying to find a solution for the seventh legislative process ("`Zwanzigste Verordnung zur Änderung von Anlagen des Betäubungsmittelgesetzes"`) in order to apply this solution to every legislative process.

This is my current work status:

```
if(!require("rvest")) install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest) #for html_attr & read_html

if(!require("dplyr")) install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr) # for %>%

if(!require("stringr")) install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr) # for str_detect()

if(!require("magrittr")) install.packages("magrittr")
library(magrittr) # for extract()  [within pipes]

page <- read_html("https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/service/gesetze-und-verordnungen.html")

#Gesetz.Link -> here "Inkrafttreten"
    #Gesetz.Link <- lapply(1:72, function(x){
      x <- 7 # for demonstration reasons
      node.with.data <- html_nodes(page, css = paste0("#skiplink2maincontent > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2 > div:nth-child(",x*2,") > div > div > div.panel-body > p")) %>%
        extract(
          str_detect(html_text(html_nodes(page, css = paste0("#skiplink2maincontent > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2 > div:nth-child(",x*2,") > div > div > div.panel-body > p"))),
                     "Inkrafttreten")
        ) 
      
      link <-  node.with.data %>%
        html_children() %>%
        extract(
          str_detect(html_text(html_nodes(node.with.data, xpath = paste0("text()"))),
                     "Inkrafttreten")
        ) %>%
        html_attr("href")
      
      ifelse(length(node.with.data)==0, NA, link)  # set link to "NA" if there is no Link to "Referentenentwurf"
      
    #}) %>% 
    #  unlist()
```

(I have commented out the application for the entire website so that the solution can be related to the seventh element.)

The problem is, that there **can be** several URLs linked to each document (here "Download" & "Stellungnahmen" are linked to "Referentenentwurf"). This lead to an error of my syntax.

Is there any way to extract the `nth-element` within after another element? So there could be a check if the "text()"-element is "Referentenentwurf" and then extract the first element behind it

```
-> "<a href="/fileadmin/Dateien/3_Downloads/Gesetze_und_Verordnungen/GuV/B/2020-03-04_RefE_20-BtMAEndV.pdf" ...>".
```

I would be very grateful for tips on how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond that, I took the freedom to change a few things in your code and try to get you where you want:
My stab at this is to go into the list of Verordnungen/Gesetze/etc., find the `div.panel-body > p` as you do and within that the first link that refers to a downloadable document, by searching for a `href` containing "/fileadmin/Dateien" using xpath.

Looks like this:

```
library(purrr)
library(xml2)

html_nodes(page, css = '#skiplink2maincontent > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2 > div') %>%
  map(~{
    .x %>%
      xml_find_first('./div/div/div[contains(@class,"panel-body")]/p//a[contains(@href,"/fileadmin/Dateien")]') %>%
      xml_attr('href')
  })
```

//update:
If the above assumption doesn't work for you and you really just want to check for  "first `a`-tag after 'Referentenentwurf' in the p-element", the following does get you that. However, I couldn't make it as "elegant" and just used a regex :)

```
html_nodes(page, css = '#skiplink2maincontent > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2 > div') %>%
  map(~{
    .x %>%
      xml_find_first('./div/div/div[contains(@class,"panel-body")]/p') %>%
      as.character() %>%
      str_extract_all('(?<=Referentenentwurf.{0,10000})(?<=<a href=")[^"]*(?=")') %>%
      unlist() %>%
      first()
    })
```